# set a cookie in middleware

Tags: node.js, cookies

If the user session expired, I want to generate a new access token using refresh token.
I found a curl command to generate google tokens here: https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/cff75182aac5fa42930a09f58b63a309
and it works.

```js
googleDriveRouter.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    //verify if google auth token is set in the cookies and not expired
    let googleAuthToken = req.cookies['google-auth-session'];
    const refresh_token = req.cookies['google-auth-refresh-token'];
    // curl commad :
    //     curl \
    // --request POST \
    // --data 'client_id=***&client_secret=***&refresh_token=*****&grant_type=refresh_token' \
    // https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

    
    /**
     * @params refreshToken refresh token
     * @returns access token
     * @describe get a new access token from refresh token
    */

    if(!googleAuthToken && refresh_token) { //if token is expired,  then generate a new token if refresh token is set {
        const config ={
            params : {
                client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
                refresh_token: refresh_token,
                grant_type: 'refresh_token'
            
            }
        };
        const response = await axios.post(
            'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
            config.params,
        );
        googleAuthToken = response.data.access_token;
        //set access token as a cookie for session
        res.cookie('google-auth-session', googleAuthToken, { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true });
        console.log("middleware", response.data);
    }

    
    next();
});
```

When I do console.log I get this information :

```bash
middleware {
  access_token: '********3',
  expires_in: 3599,
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  id_token: '****'     
}
```

but when i look in cookies google-auth-session is still empty. What I'm doing wrong ?

res.cookie('google-auth-session', googleAuthToken, { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true });

Is it wrong to do it this way ?

Comment: How do you send the response back to the user in the next step?

Comment: Don't really understand.  I use cookie to save user session . And when I need I use bearer token (where token=req.cookies[ google-auth-session cookie.]

Comment: How do you check that the cookie is empty?

Comment: which cookie ?  if token is expired (1h),  then I generate a new token if refresh token is set  
    if  (!googleAuthToken && refresh_token) {